# Magento2.3.0 How to do in left side navigation custom category tree structure create it?

Tags: custom, layered-navigation, magento2.3.0, category-tree

I am using Magento2.3.0 I need in left side layer navigation instead replace category section  there our  custom category tree display on it and its work as on fronted side only.If any one this type of customization reply me.

I'm using for layer navigation third party module but in this module by default category display on it left side but we want to default instead custom category tree display in left side.

I am waiting reply

any help will be appreciated.